# Use local .NET Core system libraries instead of adding them to every package

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Our client has complained about the count of `.dll` files in the .NET Core app we made for them. Their dissatisfaction persists even after we explained that this is how .NET Core works.

Now I do understand their position completely, my jaw dropped too when I created the package for the first time:

[image]

Note how small the scroll bar is. Most of the library names begin with `Microsoft.` or `System.` - those that don't are libraries that I use and installed manually.

So the question is: is there anything I can do about this to make our client happy? Aren't the `System.*` libraries already installed on their machine as a part of .NET Core runtime?

We're targeting .NET Core 1.0 at this moment.

Comment: This question has me bemused. What difference does it make to the client if all the required namespaces etc are in one massive dll, or hundreds of small ones? No doubt cue massive downvoting but I would still like to know.

Comment: "Our client has complained about the count of .dll files", don't they have anything else more productive to do? Seriously, that complain doesn't make sense. Anyway, that supposedly was fixed in .NET 4.7.1 and .NET Core 2. What are you targeting?

Comment: glad I'm not the only one! Hope the client never looks in a node_modules folder!

Comment: `ASP.NET Core ships entirely as NuGet packages. Using NuGet packages allows you to optimize your app to include only the necessary dependencies.` isnt it correct from microsoft?

Comment: @ojf You mean the 700 sub-folders inside node_modules? ;)

Comment: Guys of course, this is the kind of situation when the client is trying to be tech savvy but isn't. But in the end, they're the ones paying the money, so if they want us to waste time dealing with libraries instead of implementing features, that's what they get. And from user perspective, I totally understand their issue with this.

Comment: See [Framework-dependent deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/index#framework-dependent-deployments-fdd)

Comment: Is it possible for you to retarget to .NET Core 2? Also, what's the reason for being in 1.0 which is not supported anymore?

Comment: Show them this question on SO. Seriously.

Comment: I have a hunch you can't do better if targeting .NET Core 1.0 - that target means the compiler "knows" you might be missing those System.* modules.

Comment: @TomášZato: I disagree actually. This isn't at all a reasonable perspective. Look at the directory of any commercial application and you'll see DLLs and such there as well. This is *normal*, and it doesn't matter at all whether the app has 1 DLL or 1000. It doesn't effect anything. The only way to remove DLL dependencies is to literally write all functionality from scratch. Then, you'll have just one DLL, but your app will take 10 years and a 100 developers to create. If your client wants to pay for that, great. Otherwise, STFU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create [two types of deployments for .NET Core applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/index#framework-dependent-deployments-fdd):

- Framework-dependent deployment
- Self-contained deployment

It seems you need Framework-dependent deployments (FDD).

Portable (FDD) application is similar to the traditional .NET Framework application. In this case, a certain version of the .NET Core Framework (also known as shared framework, .NET Core Runtime, redist) should be on the target computer, and when the host starts, the process will load Core CLR, Core FX from the frame folder.

Artifacts of the same Portable Application for different versions of the .NET Core platform
[image]

You can see what [Directory structure of published ASP.NET Core apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/directory-structure) should be

To run Portable applications, at least one .NET Core Runtime (shared framework) must be installed on the target machine. The framework files (s) are stored in the `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared` folder.

Comment: Then client would be upset that he has to install something before running application.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, we'll look into this. I had problems with library compatibility for 2.0 though. I'll do some googling on retargeting.

Answer (score 1):

Core is designed to do this. In old .NET Framework apps, there's a runtime dependency on .NET Framework, i.e. the end-user must have the version of the .NET Framework the application targets installed on the machine as well. Core takes a different approach; it brings everything it needs into the build. As a result, you can drop this folder on any machine, no matter how it's set up and "run" it. (Now technically, you need dotnet.exe in order to run it, unless you build as an executable, but that's just to run the main app DLL.)

Anyways, this is by design, and it's actually much better when you think about it. Your app has just the dependencies it actually needs and nothing else. You don't have to worry about external things like what version of .NET Framework is installed, etc.

That said, I know there's some third-party applications (mostly commercial) that can enable you to "bundle" DLLs or even package up everything into a single executable. However, I'm not sure how compatible, if at all, these are with .NET Core. Still, if your client insists, I'd just see if you can find some tool that does that and essentially "hide" the DLLs.

Comment: The official documentation disagrees with you: "For an FDD, you deploy only your app and any third-party dependencies. You don't have to deploy .NET Core, since your app will use the version of .NET Core that's present on the target system. This is the default deployment model for .NET Core apps."

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Could you link to the docs_ I§d like to find out if we can just deploy with 3rd party libs.

Comment: @TomášZato Marusyk already linked in the question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/index#framework-dependent-deployments-fdd

Comment: @Chris, Yeah, I already told pretty much all that's in your answer to the higher ups, but they insist. This question really isn't why is it the way it is, I already know that. It's about alternative options if client keeps pushing this.

Comment: @TomášZato - Alternative option: Delete the DLLs and shrug when it doesn't work.